# Can't do 'helm install' on cluster. Tiller was installed by gitab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I created a cluster in GKE using Gitlab and installed Helm & Tiller and some other stuffs like ingress and gitlab runner using gitab's interface. But when I try to install something using helm from gcloud, it gives "Error: Transport is closing".

I did `gcloud container clusters get-credentials ...`.

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

NAMESPACE               NAME                                                     READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default                 jaeger-deployment-59ffb979c8-lmjk5                       1/1       Running   0          17h
gitlab-managed-apps     certmanager-cert-manager-6c8cd9f9bf-67wnh                1/1       Running   0          17h
gitlab-managed-apps     ingress-nginx-ingress-controller-75c4d99549-x66n4        1/1       Running   0          21h
gitlab-managed-apps     ingress-nginx-ingress-default-backend-6f58fb5f56-pvv2f   1/1       Running   0          21h
gitlab-managed-apps     prometheus-kube-state-metrics-6584885ccf-hr8fw           1/1       Running   0          22h
gitlab-managed-apps     prometheus-prometheus-server-69b9f444df-htxsq            2/2       Running   0          22h
gitlab-managed-apps     runner-gitlab-runner-56798d9d9d-nljqn                    1/1       Running   0          22h
gitlab-managed-apps     tiller-deploy-74f5d65d77-xk6cc                           1/1       Running   0          22h
kube-system             heapster-v1.6.0-beta.1-7bdb4fd8f9-t8bq9                  2/2       Running   0          22h
kube-system             kube-dns-7549f99fcc-bhg9t                                4/4       Running   0          22h
kube-system             kube-dns-autoscaler-67c97c87fb-4vz9t                     1/1       Running   0          22h
kube-system             kube-proxy-gke-cluster2-pool-1-05abcbc6-0s6j             1/1       Running   0          20h
kube-system             kube-proxy-gke-cluster2-pool-2-67e57524-ht5p             1/1       Running   0          22h
kube-system             metrics-server-v0.2.1-fd596d746-289nd                    2/2       Running   0          22h
visual-react-10450736   production-847c7d879c-z4h5t                              1/1       Running   0          22h
visual-react-10450736   production-postgres-64cfcf9464-jr74c                     1/1       Running   0          22h
```

```
$ ./helm install stable/wordpress --tiller-namespace gitlab-managed-apps --name wordpress

E0127 10:27:29.790366     418 portforward.go:331] an error occurred forwarding 39113 -> 44134: error forwarding port 44134 to pod 86b33bdc7bc30c08d98fe44c0772517c344dd1bdfefa290b46e82bf84959cb6f, uid : exit status 1: 2019/01/27 04:57:29 socat[11124] E write(5, 0x14ed120, 186): Broken pipe

Error: transport is closing
```

Another one

```
$ ./helm install incubator/jaeger --tiller-namespace gitlab-managed-apps --name jaeger --set elasticsearch.rbac.create=true --set provisionDataStore.cassandra=false --set provisionDataStore.elasticsearch=true --set storage.type=elasticsearch

E0127 10:30:24.591751     429 portforward.go:331] an error occurred forwarding 45597 -> 44134: error forwarding port 44134 to pod 86b33bdc7bc30c08d98fe44c0772517c344dd1bdfefa290b46e82bf84959cb6f, uid : exit status 1: 2019/01/27 05:00:24 socat[13937] E write(5, 0x233d120, 8192): Connection reset by peer

Error: transport is closing
```

I tried forwarding ports myself and it never returns to prompt, takes forever.
`kubectl port-forward --namespace gitlab-managed-apps tiller-deploy 39113:44134`

Apparently installing anything from Gitab's ui uses Helm and those do not fail. Yet doing so from shell fails. Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try to fix it by **helm init --wait**? Can you try to delete tiller deployment and recreate it? I've found some helpful threads [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483283/kubernetes-helm-lost-connection-to-pod-and-transport-is-closing-errors) [2](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/2560#issuecomment-307058794) [3](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/2560#issuecomment-308248533) [4](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/2025) which explained more about the similar issue and commands.

Comment: I removed the whole cluster. For now I'll stick to VMs. I'll try again sometime else.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but I'll share this just in case someone else struggles with this issue. I've found an answer in the gitlab forums: [HERE](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/orphaned-apps-in-gitlab-managed-apps-namespace/22717/15).

The trick is to export and decode the certificates from the tiller service account and pass them as arguments to helm like this:

```
helm list --tiller-connection-timeout 30 --tls --tls-ca-cert tiller-ca.crt --tls-cert tiller.crt --tls-key tiller.key ---all --tiller-namespace gitlab-managed-apps
```

Comment: Right now I'm not using Kubernetes. Once I get back to it I'll try out your suggestion and accept the answer if it works.